# Scale control in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How do I add a scale control in Mapbox GL JS?

This is what I've tried:

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Scale({position: 'bottom-left'}));
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: mapboxgl.Scale is not a constructor
```

I'm using Mapbox GL JS version 0.32.1 and I thought [scale controls were added in version 0.23](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/2940#issuecomment-238882361). The map itself is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Mapbox API docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#scalecontrol) and then try

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.ScaleControl());
```

It's placed at the bottom left by default.